# Browsing local files through webpage. (directory listing and browsing)

Tags: java, file, local, apache2.2

How do fellow coders. I have been playing with apache. Frankly it is an underrated tool! However it is a little bit limited. I would like to attempt to create a webpage that will show the local files. Currently, my page looks like this:

[image]

I want to create a webpage hosted locally to view my files in a more shiney way. So that got me thinking. Is there a java applet, that I could use that is a little more professional? Can this be done? I am open to other methods though. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: I've tried going here: http://perishablepress.com/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/ but it just blatantly confused me. Anyone have any example .htaccess file?

Comment: Nobody? :( I feel lonly...